# Alternative connection to database without PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, database

Objective: Update prices of products between databases: Shop's server DB has the latest prices and website's DB need to be updated accordingly with any "each 24 hours" script (I'll look this up later).

I'm using Ionos as hosting for the website, and The server is shared, so I can't touch php.ini or add files for php.

I'm trying to connect to a SQL server DB, but since it requires dll libraries to be installed and to modify the php.ini, I can't do that.

I can't either make it from *the other side*, If I make it from an external server in order to update the prices of the website, they don't allow to make connections out of the context of the server.

So, I know that the solution is to upgrade the hosting's plan and pay more and so on, so I have a virtual server for my own. But before doing that, is there any other way to establish this connection without using php? Is there something else that allows me to create a DB connection?

The fatal errors appears as soon as `sqlsrv_connect` is read as there is no library to load this function.

```
$serverName = "x, 0000"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"x", "UID"=>"x", "PWD"=>"xxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Edit: Comes to my mind... Maybe a solution would be to tell this php file to load php.ini and so on from another server if that's possible?

Comment: So what's the question?  You can't install what is necessary to connect to the DB and you can't connect remotely.  Why would the host provide a SQL server database but no way to connect to it?

Comment: Did you ask your host what their recommended way of connecting to a SQL Server database?

Comment: @AbraCadaver The daily price changes are in SQL Server in a local DB. I need to read this local db to import the prices into the website's DB (mysql) and update them.

Comment: why not make a JSON endpoint on the server with the db? secure it, and then make a curl call to  grab the JSON, and process

Comment: @Diado They way for them is to upgrade the hosting plan and pay more for it. Who would say.

Comment: well you either upgrade, or make an endpoint your php can call, json_decode, and then update the db. here's the upgrade link https://www.ionos.co.uk/cloud/sql-server-hosting

Comment: @delboy1978uk I'm not very experienced, I actually didn't understand your proposition. An actual example would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: something like this https://3v4l.org/Gpi28

Comment: I have added a very basic example answer to help you call the db server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly call a JSON endpoint on your DB server (secure the endpoint though (out of scope for my answer)) https://3v4l.org/Gpi28

```
<?php

// MSSQL server side

$data = [
    1 => 'hello',
    2 => 'world',
];

// Imagine $data above is the array of rows returned by the db query

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;


// IONOS Side
$json = file_get_contents('http://your-database-server/some/url/or/other');
$data = json_decode(true);
// Now do your updates

// NB This is an INSECURE example, people who know the URL can see this data!
```

Comment: I'll ask the guy that created the table view in the local side if he can output a json. I'll need also to read about how to secure a json. I believe this may work. Thank you @delboy1978uk